# как из строки убрать уникальный символ?

Tags: python, строки

Вот есть абстрактная строчка

```
a = "abcd8efg"
```

как отсюда убрать цифру 8?
пробовал так:

```
a = "abcd8efg"
a = int(a)
a = a - 9
```

и как это сделать?

Comment: ход мыслей тут - ``a = int(a)`` я еще могу понять (хоть он и базируется на неправильном понимании того, что делает ``int()``). А вот что вы хотели сделать тут - ``a = a - 9``?

Comment: я вообще не понял вопроса. уникальность "буквы" в чем? вы ее сами определяете?

Comment: Предположу, что уникальность "буквы" в том, что она не буква, а цифра

Answer (score 2):

Способов масса, выбирайте понравившийся

```
a = "abcd8efg"
a = a[:a.find("8")] + a[a.find("8")+1:]

a = "abcd8efg"
a = a.replace("8", "")

import re
a = "abcd8efg"
a = re.sub(r"[0-9]", "", a)
```

Последний убирает все цифры, первые два - только 8

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно каково условие, почему именно 8 - она задана или по каким-то критериям выбирается? Если заранее задана, то как вариант:

```
a = "abcd8efg"
a = ''.join(i for i in a if i != '8')
print(a)
# abcdefg
```

Answer (score 1):

Тоже способ

```
a = "abcd8efg"
print(''.join(filter(str.isalpha, a)))
```